# Какой шаблон применяется для создания desktop-приложений в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Нужен подходящий для JavaFX шаблон проектирования, который будет разделять логику приложения.

Например в WPF это MVVM. Там для этого и Binding есть. Что есть подобного в JavaFX? И есть ли какой-то ресурс на котором все это демонстрируется?

*P.S. MVVM тоже ведь в JavaFX имеет место быть? Тогда поделитесь, пожалуйста, ссылкой на пример использования этого шаблона!*

Comment: Стояло бы в вопросе упомянуть, чем не подходят примеры, которые находятся по фразе "mvvm javafx example".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java FX это просто библиотека для создания десктоп приложений на Java. Паттерн разработчик может выбрать любой, который соответствует решаемой задаче либо просто ему хорошо знаком или нравится.

Если Вас интересует именно MVVM, то его реализация обсуждалась в сети. Вот вопрос по этой теме на enSO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735768/mvvm-in-javafx-controls-that-have-a-data-model.

Также для Java FX есть целый MVVM фреймворк: https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и полезные ссылки!